# Emacs/tramp: sudo to root on localhost hangs after asking for password

Tags: sudo, emacs, tramp

Can't use the su method, since I don't really want to veer from the Ubuntu default too much.  ssh is right out (for localhost?  I ask you!).

It shows a "Waiting for prompts from remote shell".  And that's it, apparently.  Or is it just *that* incredibly slow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just upgrade tramp to 2.1.18 (if you are against emacs-23.1)

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tramp/tramp-2.1.18.tar.gz
$ tar xvf tramp-2.1.18.tar.gz
$ cd tramp-2.1.18
$ ./configure --with-contrib
$ make 
$ sudo make install
```

This will install new tramp to */usr/local/share/emacs*

Emacs will find it automagically.

P.S. This operation needs texinfo and libgnome2-dev.

Comment: Thanks -- this worked. Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with Emacs 23.1.1. Installed latest 2.1 tramp (2.1.19) and dependencies. My username on the remote machine is different to my local username so I used "USERNAME@%h" in your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465567/how-to-use-ssh-and-sudo-together-with-tramp-in-emacs/